# Label Text to the right to SMA moving averages

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I need your help to resolve a problem.

I want a label to the right of the end of my moving averages like this pictures:

[enter image description here][1]

This is the code that make the error "line 25: The 'timeframe' argument is incompatible with functions that have side effects."

The line 25 is:

var day1Label = label.new(x = bar_index, y = day1, style = label.style_label_left, textcolor = #2196F3, text = "textTest")

could you help me please? Thanks

````
indicator(title="Jacopo lines T-3/T-2/T-1/T/T+1/T+2/T+3/T+4", overlay=true, timeframe="60")

day1 = ta.sma(close, 24)
day2 = ta.sma(close, 48)
day4 = ta.sma(close, 96)
day8 = ta.sma(close, 192)
day16 = ta.sma(close, 384)
day32 = ta.sma(close, 768)
day64 = ta.sma(close, 1536)
day128 = ta.sma(close, 3072)

plot(day1, color = #2196F3, style=plot.style_cross)
plot(day2, color = #FF9800, style=plot.style_cross)
plot(day4, color = #4CAF50, style=plot.style_cross)
plot(day8, color = #00BCD4, style=plot.style_cross)
plot(day16, color = #FF5252, style=plot.style_cross)
plot(day32, color = #E040FB, style=plot.style_cross)
plot(day64, color = #FF9800, style=plot.style_cross)
plot(day128, color = #FFFFFF, style=plot.style_cross)

var day1Label = label.new(x = bar_index, y = day1, style = label.style_label_left, textcolor = color.yellow, text = "textTest")

label.set_xy(day1Label, x = bar_index, y = day1) ```
````

Comment: Your picture is missing

Comment: You can't use labels/boxes/lines/tables if you are using the timeframe argument in indicator()

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to remove this **timeframe="60"** and use the **request.security** function instead: [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request{dot}security](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dsecurity)

The code probably doesn't understand how to translate the bar_index without a the request.security() call

Answer (score 0):

You can use the timeframe in request the security and then set the label text too with the latest value, example below

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Jacopo lines T-3/T-2/T-1/T/T+1/T+2/T+3/T+4", overlay=true)

cls=request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"60",close)

day1 = ta.sma(cls, 24)
day2 = ta.sma(cls, 48)
day4 = ta.sma(cls, 96)
day8 = ta.sma(cls, 192)
day16 = ta.sma(cls, 384)
day32 = ta.sma(cls, 768)
day64 = ta.sma(cls, 1536)
day128 = ta.sma(cls, 3072)

plot(day1, color = #2196F3, style=plot.style_cross)
plot(day2, color = #FF9800, style=plot.style_cross)
plot(day4, color = #4CAF50, style=plot.style_cross)
plot(day8, color = #00BCD4, style=plot.style_cross)
plot(day16, color = #FF5252, style=plot.style_cross)
plot(day32, color = #E040FB, style=plot.style_cross)
plot(day64, color = #FF9800, style=plot.style_cross)
plot(day128, color = #FFFFFF, style=plot.style_cross)

var day1Label = label.new(x = bar_index, y = day1, style = label.style_label_left, textcolor = color.yellow, text = "textTest")

label.set_xy(day1Label, x = bar_index, y = day1)
label.set_text(day1Label,text = str.tostring(day1))
```